# Would adding encryption to an MPLS provide additional protection for application access which is over TLS?

Tags: encryption, tls

I have users at a remote site who access business application via an MPLS. The applications use HTTPS (TLS). The MPLS connection that we have is non-encrypted.  The data is sensitive.
Would adding encryption to the MPLS provide additional protection?

How does MPLS(with no encryption) handle TLS traffic?
Can data be read whilst in transit by the provider? I ask as i know traffic is covered before it transverses MPLS networks.

Comment: You might need to provide more information about what "via an MPLS" means. Where is the application client actually running? Where is the user? How exposed is the connection between them? What, _exactly_, is running over that connection (e.g. if you look at it in Wireshark what would you see)?

Comment: This question needs more information and context, is not clear the usage of MPLS as well as the services that use TLS. MPLS works at layer 2 and TLS at layer 7.